# Duda consulta a sql desde php con caracteres especiales

Tags: php, sql-server

espero podáis ayudarme con esta duda,

Dado el siguiente codigo php que se conecta a una base de datos sql server:

```
$sql = "select * from tabla1 where campo1 like '%ñ%'" ;
$datos = $this->objeto->listar() ;
$numRegistros = sqlsrv_row_num($datos) ;
print_r($numRegistros) ;
```

El resultado en pantalla es 0. Si le quito el where el resultado son 219, es decir,  todos los registros de la tabla. 
 Se que en la tabla hay al menos 20 resultados con ñ.  Es decir,  no reconoce los caracteres especiales al hacer el where. Pasa lo mismo con los acentos.

La consulta es correcta,  copiada y pegada en el management studio devuelve los 20 resultados. Las funciones utf8_encode y utf8_decode no me sirve,  o al menos no se como hacerlo.

Podeis ayudarme con el problema?

Comment: Por favor, añade la definición de la tabla y algún dato de prueba que intentas obtener con la consulta incluyendo el WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi caso aplico dos técnicas para poder realizar las búsquedas con caracteres acentuados.

Por el lado de PHP
    utf8_decode('áéíóúñ')

http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-decode.php

Y por el lado de SQLServer un cotejamiento que permita hacer la búsqueda insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas, acentos y ancho donde `Latin1_General_CI_AI` cumple con estas reglas.

Ej:

```
nombre
-------
Ramón
Ramon

SELECT nombre FROM Tabla WHERE nombre LIKE '%ó%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

En este caso el resultado será que ambos registros cumplen con la condición al especificar que la comparación es insensible a los caracteres acentuados.

Para conocer la especificación de cada cotejamiento `COLALTE` puedes consultarlos en tu mismo motor:

```
SELECT * FROM  sys.fn_HelpCollations() 
WHERE name like ('%Latin1_General_CI_AI%')
ORDER BY name;

-----------------------
Latin1_General_CI_AI: 
Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive
```

Breve explicación y ejemplo sobre el ancho de las cadenas de texto.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/14/sql-server-example-of-width-sensitive-and-width-insensitive-collation/

Comment: Perfecto, ambas opciones funcionan a la perfecccion. Ya habia intentado usar utf8_decode, que me parecia lo mas apropiado y facil en mi caso, pero algo debi hacer mal. Esta vez ha funcionado como debe.

Answer (score 1):

Con utf8_decode() se debería de resolver el problema.

```
$sql = "select * from tabla1 where campo1 like '%".utf8_decode("ñ")."%'";
//echo $sql; Si deseas imprimir la consulta en pantalla.
$datos = $this->objeto->listar() ;
$registros = sqlsrv_row_num($datos) ;
print_r($registros) ;
```

> 1. Sanitización y seguridad en los parámetros es tu responsabilidad, es importante para prevenir inyección SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar utilizando el like collate ?

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE campo1 LIKE '%ñ%' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Espero te sea de utilidad

Answer (score 0):

Con un utf8 resolvería tu problema, esto va al momento de hacer conexión con la base de datos.

Anexo ejemplo:

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','password','db');

**mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');** // **linea a colocar para que puedas manejar caracteres especiales.**

Cabe recalcar que el campo de la tabla1 debe tener **cotejamiento (latin1_swedish_ci)** al menos así me funciono a mi.

Haciendo lo anterior, no necesitar modificar tu consulta de sql.

Saludos.

Comment: El único problema con tu respuesta Noel es que está utilizando como motor de datos a SQLServer. Saludos

Comment: Estoy utilizando MySQL, no sé si tenga alguna diferencia entre la duda principal y la solución que di.

Comment: La verdad si dado que hay una serie de cotejamientos que tienen distintas condiciones para hacer búsquedas de cadenas, al menos en el caso de SQLServer si no especificas el cotejamiento en la comparación no vas a tener los resultados que esperas o que en este caso el OP espera.

Comment: Vale, es bueno saberlo.